# codepage or arabic characters

Tags: java, eclipse, codepages

Consider this code:

```
 public class lamAlifTestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String a = "لا";
       String b = "a";

       byte[] y = a.getBytes(); // -28 & -57
       byte[] z = b.getBytes(); // 97


       System.out.println("Special character length: " + y.length);
       System.out.println("Normal character length: " + z.length);

    }
 }
```

The special character takes 2 bytes using eclipse's default codepage Cp1046.
Is there a codepage where this character only takes 1 byte?
the character is called lam-alif.

How can i get eclipse/java to use this codepage where the character is only taking 1 byte?
I tried to change the codepage in the properties of the file, but it's taking any effect?

http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/x-IBM1046/list.htm

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by *codepage*? Btw Java uses UTF-16 by default, not an IBM coding scheme.

Comment: I believe that wide characters were originally created so that international symbols could all be represented as a single char datatype.  So, I don't think an arabic character can be represented as 1 byte.  Also, I believe it's now the standard to use wide characters in practice.

Comment: The string in the sample is actually two characters: `ل`  and `ا`, and they take up two bytes *each* in Java's favourite encoding UTF-16 (if by ‘byte’ we mean eight bits). Good luck finding *any* encoding system that will fit them into a single byte. In what context is it a problem to have a few more bytes anyway?

Comment: It looks to me like the character set you linked to is using 2 byte characters for the Arabic glyphs.  clicking on the link for the individual character leads to a page describing the specific character and it looks like the UTF-8 is a multibyte character set while the UTF-16 is a single character, two byte character set.

Comment: @RichardChambers It's a common misconception that UTF-16 is a fixed-width system; it uses two or four bytes per character (for some definition of ‘character’).

Comment: @Biffen, misconception or not, the linked to page uses two byte values that are labeled as UTF-16.

Comment: This Mozilla bugzilla report talks to IBM-1046 to Unicode https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210629

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, *some* characters fit in a single UTF-16 unit, i.e. two bytes, [but others need two units, i.e. four bytes](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D11E/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks all for you replies. I need it for a large amount of fixed-length strings where this character is showing. 
(generated software)